# MySQL Insert Records from Multiple Tables to New Table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to populate a new table with records from 2 other tables.

period_states is new/empty

```
 period_states
   id
   period_id
   sla_id
```

periods - contains 15 records

```
periods
  id
```

slas - contains 84 records

```
slas
  id
```

I need to populate period_states with each existing sla_id having each exiting period_id.  So, ultimately there should be 1260 records in period_states.

Any idea how to automate this?  It would be a nightmare to populate manually...

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Is the `id` field in table `period_states` set as `auto_increment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO period_states
(period_id, sla_id)
SELECT periods.id, slas.id
FROM periods
CROSS JOIN slas
```

Comment: I'm not saying my answer is wrong, but judging from the comments, it looks like you meant to accept @spencer7593's answer

Comment: your answer is right. Since this is the 'selected' answer, I will add a comment here that in MySQL, it's true that `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` are all synonymous.  The ANSI SQL spec defines the `CROSS JOIN` as a join without a condition that produces a Cartesian product. Including the `CROSS` keyword in the statement (even where it isn't required) does serve as documentation (to remove ambiguity and to make the intent more clear), and makes the statement more portable to other RDBMSs.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer for the sake of future readers. Also up voted your answer for completeness

Answer (score 6):

If the `id` column of period states is defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then this should work:

```
INSERT INTO period_states (period_id, sla_id)
SELECT p.id AS period_id
     , s.id AS sla_id
  FROM periods p
 CROSS
  JOIN slas s
```

And here's an example of one way to supply a value for the `id` column:

```
INSERT INTO period_states (id, period_id, sla_id)
SELECT @myid := @myid + 1 AS id
     , p.id AS period_id
     , s.id AS sla_id
  FROM periods p
 CROSS
  JOIN slas s
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @myid := 0) m
```

Comment: Awesome - that was it.  it's the "cross" function I didn't know.  Yes, period_states id is auto-incremented.  Thank you bunches!

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into period_states select null, periods.id, slas.id from periods, slas
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "insert into.... select"  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html syntax.  ... pretty much like what the other answers have displayed.