# joining 2 tables and save into third with duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (many to many) :

### Student

```
+-------------------+
| ids | Name |Address|
+-------------------+
| 1  | Bob  |LA     |  
| 2  | Ace  |NY     | 
| 3  | Test |LA     |    
+-------------------+
```

### Professor

```
+-------------------+
| idp | Name |Address|
+-------------------+
| 1  | Jon  |LA     |  
| 2  | Taz  |LA     | 
| 3  | Test |LA     |    
+-------------------+
```

I want to display all students who have Jon as professor. In order to do that i  guess I need a 3rd table with foreign keys on idp and ids?

How do I join the two tables into one?

Also, how do I display (using union) the names of the people living in LA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Student with just one Professor:**

A third table is not necessary, just add that foreign key (idp = Professor ID) in the Student Table so that you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM Student 
    JOIN Professor ON Student.idp = Professor.idp 
    WHERE Professor.Name = 'Jon'
```

and this way you will get all the students who have Jon as their Professor.

**A Student multiple professors**

In case that a student have multiple professors. For sure you will need that third table then. Somethin like this:

```
Student_Professor {StudentID, ProfessorID} // Compound key
```

Another way to create that third table would be:

```
Student_Professor {StudentProfessorID, StudentID, ProfessorID}
```

where StudentProfessorID is your primary key and the rest foreign keys.. The advantage with this case is that you will only have to deal with one primary key instead of the compound one.

**Query**

Assuming that the third table is like this: Student_Professor {StudentID, ProfessorID}

We could use:

```
SELECT * FROM Student_Professor 
    JOIN Student ON Student.StudentID = Student_Professor.StudentID
    JOIN Professor ON Professor.ProfessorID = Student_Professor.ProfessorID
WHERE Professor.Name = 'Jon'
```

Comment: Won't adding a foreign key(idp = Professor ID) in the Student Table restrict me with each student having just one professor? I want a many to many relationship (each student can have multiple professors and other way around)

Comment: Yes, in that case you will need a third table. I updated my answer check it out.

Comment: And I insert the values into the 3rd table manually ? Can't i use join to merge the old 2 ?

Comment: For Sure, Let write that query for you.! right now

Comment: Not a problem my dear friend, If you use the first approach (The compound key).. You can do something similar to this: SELECT * FROM Student_Professor 
 JOIN Student ON Student.StudentID = Student_Professor.StudentID
 JOIN Professor ON Professor.ProfessorID = Student_Professor.ProfessorID
WHERE Professor.Name = 'Jon'

Answer (score 0):

To filter data you'll need to make use of a 'where' clause

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

The where clause will go at the end of your statement and will be of this syntax:

```
SELECT *columns* FROM *table* WHERE *some condition*
```

The union operator is used to join two statements together.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

So,

```
SELECT *columns* FROM *table*
UNION
SELECT *columns* FROM *table*
```

Add a where clause onto the end of the union and you have your answer for which people live in LA.

To join two tables together that have a many to many relationship you will need to use what's called a mapping table.  That is, a table with two columns.  One for a professor id, and another for a student id, that describes every relationship that exists between every professor and every student.

Comment: The third table must be populated manually? Can't I join the two existing tables into one ?

Comment: @user3171222 How do you currently know which students have which professors?

Comment: The task does not specify which students have which professors, that's why I assume all students have all professors.

Comment: @user3171222 If that's the case, look into inserting the ID, student ID, and professor ID into the third table via a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that each student has each professor, you can create the records in your junction table through a cross join as shown here: [MySQL Insert Records from Multiple Tables to New Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799565/mysql-insert-records-from-multiple-tables-to-new-table)

A cross join will join every row from table A with every row from table B, resulting in a Cartesian product.

Assuming a table called Student_Professor with columns StudentId and ProfessorId:

```
insert into Student_Professor (StudentId, ProfessorId)
select Student.ids, Professor.idp
from Student
cross join Professor
```